# ToolBar is overlapping on my RelativeLayout when i use By default toolBar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I've added Default `Toolbar` in my current application.

But when I added this toolBar my "Hello world" `textview`  is not appearing.

How to resolve this problem!?

**activity_main.xml:-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.venkat.actionbarapp.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml:-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help(in activity_main.xml)

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

and remove 
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
from content_main.xml

OR

add below 2 lines in content_main.xml

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
```

and remove 
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"

Comment: no not working still my helloworld label is not appearing

Comment: add below 2 lines in content_main.xml

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"

and remove android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"